# How to post multiple objects with axios

Tags: ajax, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I am able to use JSON.stringify to post a single object literal to a webapi action. However when I try to post two parameter objects the second one comes in null (my webapi has a default value of null for the second parameter). Any ideas how to do this?